# How to enable animated webp (awebp) in React Native Fast Image?

Tags: react-native, webp, react-native-fast-image

We have [animated webp files working great in our React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625929/how-to-enable-animated-webp-for-the-image-component-in-react-native-with-expo) using the default `<Image>` component.

We were hoping to benefit from some of the caching extras built into [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image). However, it works great for everything **except** awebp files; which we have a lot of.

There are plenty of solutions in [the github issues](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues?q=animated%20webp%20) but we can't get any of them to work.

Is there a verified way to get awebp working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now `expo-image`. Use it and forget all the headaches.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/unversioned/sdk/image/

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've created some config plugins for Expo (one based on your work) which might be helpful:

https://gist.github.com/Hirbod/07c6641970c9406ff35a7271dda1f01c

Adding support for animated webP using FastImage is super easy. The Config Plugins just add 3 lines of code inside of AppDelegate.m and a single implementation line inside of android/app/build.gradle

That's it for animated webp support with FastImage.

TL;DR:

Android: add following to your android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation "com.github.zjupure:webpdecoder:2.0.4.12.0
```

iOS: Open your AppDelegate.m and right after the first AppDelegate.h import, add following:

```
#import "SDImageCodersManager.h"
#import <SDWebImageWebPCoder/SDImageWebPCoder.h>
```

Scroll down a little bit (same file) until you find this launching identifier:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

And add following after the {:

```
[SDImageCodersManager.sharedManager addCoder: SDImageWebPCoder.sharedCoder];
```

That's it. Rebuild your projects (re-run gradlew) and you have FastImage animated webP support.

P.S: when you need APNG + animated webP Support on Android, add this implementation instead:

```
 implementation 'com.github.penfeizhou.android.animation:glide-plugin:2.17.0'
```